# csv engine and mysql start

Tags: mysql, mariadb, csv, storage-engine, database-engine

my question is about speed when perform `service mysql start`.

with many tables (some not often used).

what engines consumes more or less start time ?

example: innodb --> the more tables, the more time it takes for mysql to start because it has to "load" indexes at start...

but how is it with csv engine (no indexes) ; how mysql with "deal" with those tables during a mysql start ?

Thanks

(from Comment)  I don't use innodb. I have some aria tables, tokudb tables and rocksdb tables.

Comment: I would go for the deault engine innodb, but since you are using mariadb you can try the inahced version of innodb "XtraDB"

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna - I'm pretty sure XtraDB lasted only a while; then MariaDB simply went with the stock InnoDB.

Comment: I would go with InnoDB unless there is a specific reason for some other Engine.  And MyISAM is no longer viable, so don't consider it.

Comment: @RickJames, I am not sure about this according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradb-and-innodb/ XtraDB is used in 10.1 as default storage engine. and and nither 10.2 and 10.3 release note mentoined XtraDB is removed (I havent use the last two versions myself). to be sure 100% about XtraDB I will download the latest version any if it still exist or not.

Comment: @RickJames you are right, my bad. I have tested checked supported engines on 10.3 fresh installtion and xtradb is gone.

Comment: I stand corrected.  The changelog for 10.3.1 removed XtraDB (2017-08-29).

Answer (score 0):

Innodb because its transactional does do recovery/rollback during startup. If it was an unclean shutdown this can take some time depending on tuning / data volume.

As other tables don't have extensive checks they are quick to start up.

Debian does script in myisam checks in the service start meaning the availability of MyISAM tables could be delayed.

Comment: I don't use innodb. I have some aria tables, tokudb tables and rocksdb tables.

Comment: in the past I used innodb but with 50k tables, it went awire, 15min to start, severe unrecoverable mysql crash and table corruptions. I no longer use innodb because of that

Comment: Innodb with sufficient log file size and innodb buffer pool size should be recoverable. Having a larger table cache/open-file-limit is required with 50k tables. Its hard to say what your previous problems where however innodb is still the default recommendation.

Comment: ok. but in the mean time, do you know if mysql preload csv tables at start ? thanks

Comment: No it doesn't and it shouldn't be too hard to check. Time the difference.